# Error using scrollbars in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbars, tkinter-canvas

The following program:

```
import sys
import os
os.chdir('/Users/eduardomartinez/Desktop/artista')
sys.path.append('/Users/eduardomartinez/Desktop/Imaging-1.1.6')

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

im = Image.open('samples.png')
imtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

imageframe = Frame(root)

canvas = Canvas(imageframe)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=imtk, anchor="nw")
print canvas.bbox('all')
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
scrollx = Scrollbar(imageframe, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrolly = Scrollbar(imageframe, orient=VERTICAL)
scrollx.config(command=canvas.xview)
scrolly.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)

w = imtk.width()
h = imtk.height()
cw = canvas.winfo_width()
ch = canvas.winfo_height()
if w > cw:
        scrollx.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W+E)
if h > ch:
        scrolly.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=N+S)

imageframe.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
imageframe.rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)

imageframe.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

throws errors like:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1570, in yview
res = self.tk.call(self._w, 'yview', *args)
TclError: unknown option "0": must be moveto or scroll
```

whenever I try to scroll vertically (and similar errors when scrolling horizontally). What am I doing wrong?

(Yes, stackoverflow robotic police, my post **is mostly code**. I don't think this paragraph, intended to balance my post to conform to your guidelines, improves anything)

Comment: I cannot duplicate your error. Are you certain _this exact code_ generates the error you say it does? The wording of your question is odd, when you say it returns errors "like" what you show. Is that the actual error you get when trying to scroll vertically?

Comment: It is the actual error. I have edited the code to add the four initial lines that I omitted in the OP

Comment: I thought something might be wrong in my Imaging-1.1.6 library, but I changed the program to avoid using PIL and the problem is still there

Comment: Don't know if it is legal or not. You declare the scrollbar attached to imageframe but config is to the canvas.  Try with both referring to the canvas.

Comment: I think the problem was that I didn't tell the canvas to update the scrollbars:

Comment: canvas.config(xscrollcommand=scrollx.set, yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)